# Beamer | Background fit frame title

Tags: beamer

I want my frame title background to fit the title, and to manually set the padding (e.g. like in CSS). In this example, this means that I want the background inside the red border to be orange, and the rest of the frame background to be white.

[image: example]

Code of the example:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=orange}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[plain]{This is my frame}
    Lore impsum dolor sit amet...
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the `frametitle` template to something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=orange}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\colorbox{frametitle.bg}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[plain]{This is my frame}
    Lore impsum dolor sit amet...
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @KinKyTex You're welcome!